# jquery bootstrap pagination

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap

do you have any suggestions on where can I get a plugin for bootstrap pagination? I've search on the internet and found **[this](http://uliweb.clkg.org/static/bootstrap/2.0.3/js/bootstrap-pagination.js)** problem is I don't know how to use it 'coz they don't have any documentation. Suggestion guys for jquery bootstrap pagination?

I'm using PHP

Comment: could this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400804/jquery-pagination-twitter-bootstrap

Comment: No it doesn't. I already tried that.

Comment: ha ha classic - SO the question is how to use bootstrap pagination yea? Let me check it out I might be able to hook you up with a working demo :) the site is chinese :P I cannot read anything in it, cheers

Comment: hey Tats! It's you again :D I'm looking for a plugin who has a default rendering in html when paging: `<ul><li><a>1</a></li></ul>` or something like that... I can't seem to find a great one so thats why I google bootstrap js and it lead me to that site  and [this](https://groups.google.com/group/twitter-bootstrap/browse_thread/thread/dd7008709ab540d2) one

Comment: Hiya @PeterWateber howz it? will this help you man: http://jsfiddle.net/GewE4/ made a demo if it does let me know, cooleos I will read this file now and see how it goes

Comment: It does help man but I need to use with with jquery/javascript any idea?

Comment: Saweet Bruv @PeterWateber gimme few minutes I am experimenting will update you soon. **or** in the mean while look in here I am no master in PHP but this seems more php oriented: https://github.com/jmcclell/django-bootstrap-pagination :) (still working on pagination)

Comment: that one is for python only man

Comment: Okies @PeterWateber does this help : working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VHZqj/6/show

Comment: Im using Class so functions are methods for me in javascript... can you change it? to class

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11457/discussion-between-tats-innit-and-peter-wateber)

Comment: @PeterWateber join this chat not sure what you mean by "Im using Class so functions are methods for me in javascript" it will be good to clear

Comment: i cant send any message!

Comment: okies you start the chat and I will join you: @PeterWateber

Comment: @Tats_innit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/11458/bootstrap-pagination?tab=general

Comment: my internet is broke lol

Comment: @PeterWateber I am in your invited chat now lemme know when you there: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11458/bootstrap-pagination

Comment: @PeterWateber SHould I set it as ANswer and you can accept it and upvote? :))

Answer (score 4):

Hiya **demo** :) http://jsfiddle.net/VHZqj/6/show/ *or* http://jsfiddle.net/VHZqj/6/ or http://jsfiddle.net/GewE4/

Rest the whole discussion is in the comments above.

Idea was to get the twitter bootstrap working, i.e. full setting and ui and pagination with it. Please note this doesnot use and tablesorter pagination.

Have a nice one, cheers

Comment: Nice, thanks. Do note that the navigation handling depends on the relative HTML structure of the navigation links (use of jQuery's children() and siblings())