# jquery Pagination adding content container ID

Tags: jquery

I cannot find where to add the ID for my content to make this pagination work?

Based on: [jQuery pagination + Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400804/jquery-pagination-twitter-bootstrap)

Pager works but I assume it needs to find my content container so it knows what content to paginate?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/LQbwT/

plugin: [jQuery pagination + Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400804/jquery-pagination-twitter-bootstrap)

```
<ul id="myContent">
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
</ul>


<!-- pagination -->
<div id="pager2" class="pagination"></div>

$('#pager2').pagination(100,{callback:function(page,component){
    console.info(page);
}});
```

Comment: your fiddle not include pagination plugin, add it please

Comment: I not see one, I did that http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/LQbwT/2/, so what wrong ?

Comment: It does not page and I assume because I need to tell the pager which id to page "myContent". I do not know where the plugin finds that ID.

Comment: Ok, you want to split your `#myContent` automaticaly to pages, the plugin do not do that, you need to make it yourself, make a variable and use it in callback

Comment: I do not understand how to do that. Maybe I need to find another plugin that does it all.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aMt4v/ you need this ?

Comment: other fancy way is to use scrollto plugin to nice scroll to needed element

Comment: is it possible to make http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aMt4v/ use the similar external script to customize the plugin for each different pager? eg: $('#pager2').pagination...

Comment: you mean to include functionality into plugin ? btw: scrollTo demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aMt4v/1/