# How to set up jQuery pagination + Twitter Bootstrap for JSON data received by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, twitter-bootstrap

How to set up pagination when the data is not ready when page is loaded (because data received dynamically using ajax). [There is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400804/jquery-pagination-twitter-bootstrap) and library to bind Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery pagination. I have set up [this javascript pagination library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12648135/480632).
What is the proper way to set up pagination using this library and json data received by ajax?

HTML:

```
<table id="table_of_data" class="table table-hover">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="myPager" class="pagination"></div>
```

JS:

```
    function getData(params){
        var json_url = 'MYURL';
    return $.getJSON( json_url );
    }

    var getDataDoneFunc = function(json) {


        $.each(json, function(i, jsonEntity){
           // here is another ajax
            $.getJSON( 'URL', function(data){
                 ...do smth}).done(function(){
**...add html data to #table_of_data** });

                    });
                }
            }
```